Making “staggered” lines. (screenshots attached)
What are the ways to efficiently make “staggered” lines similar to the ones attached?





You can make those very easily on a bitmap editing program at low resolution, then just upscale it and trace it.


In the left there's a rectangle. In the middle there's a straight line.
The rectangle is dragged to the Brushes panel and set to be a scatter brush. That brush is applied to the shown line and the result is in the right.
Pattern brush makes things differently:

The shape in the left contains 2 separate rectangles. It's dragged to the Brushes panel and set to be a pattern brush. In the middle that brush is applied to a straight tilted line. In the right the same brush is applied to an ellipse.
Defining a brush needs several parameters. Better to see some tutorials and, of course, Illustrator user's guide by Adobe.
